# How to map field to child object

Tags: c#, json.net

Say I have a flat JSON document like this:

```
{
    "Field1": "Value",
    "Field2": "Value"
}
```

And would like to deserialize this into a custom object `A` where `Field2` is located on a child object `B`:

```
public class A
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

How can I configure Newtonsoft JSON to handle this?

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```

Comment: What's the reason that the class structure and JSON structure can't just match here?  Perhaps you could deserialize into an intermediate object which *does* match the data structure and then write code to convert that object to your desired object structure?  Or perhaps `Field2` could be added to `A` and then you could add `B` as a calculated property?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sro1so

Answer (score 1):

**First you have to fix the property name** in A, so the deserializer knows FIeld2 is mapped to B:

```
public class A
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Field2")]
    public B B { get; set; }
}
```

Then **you have to somehow define a conversion** from a `string` value ("Value") to a `B` object. You can either define a conversion operator:

```
public class B
{
    public static explicit operator B(string source)
    {
        return new B(){Field2 = source};
    }

    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Or if that is not desirable you can define a custom value converter (simple proof of concept):

```
public class BConverter : JsonConverter<B>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, B value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override B ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, B existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string s = reader.Value as string;
        return new B() { Field2 = s };
    }
}
```

... and apply the converter to `A`'s `B` property: `[JsonConverter(typeof(BConverter))]`.

Comment: ok ... but what if he would also json `Field3` map to `Field3` of `B`?

Comment: @Selvin Good point, in that case your answer with the forwarding property wins. This has the advantage of not creating the B object if Field2 does not exist on the json, etc. (Think of mapping a string to a custom unit type, for example `"length": "3 cm"`) Both are perfect for some use cases imho.

Comment: hmm I wonder if we can use `JsonProperty` multiple times for same property ... and also what is `B existingValue` parameter in `ReadJson` ... I didn't read docs but maybe it can be used